TouchGFX build for STM32
I get 2 errors when I build target with TouchGFX.
When I build it in STM32CubeIDE there are no errors but when I build the target on TouchGFX this error appeared:
CM7/TouchGFX/target/generated/TouchGFXGeneratedHAL.cpp:28:10: fatal error: stm32h7xx_hal.h: No such file or directory
         #include <stm32h7xx_hal.h>
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        gcc/makefile_cm7:503: recipe for target 'CM7/TouchGFX/build/Riverdi_70STM32H7/CM7/TouchGFX/target/generated/TouchGFXGeneratedHAL.o' failed
        make[3]: Leaving directory 'c:/Users/Aziz/Downloads/aaaaaa/MV_Display'
        make[3]: *** [CM7/TouchGFX/build/Riverdi_70STM32H7/CM7/TouchGFX/target/generated/TouchGFXGeneratedHAL.o] Error 1
        make[2]: *** [generate_assets] Error 2
        gcc/makefile_cm7:438: recipe for target 'generate_assets' failed
        make[2]: Leaving directory 'c:/Users/Aziz/Downloads/aaaaaa/MV_Display'
        Makefile_cm7:51: recipe for target 'all' failed
        make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
        make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Aziz/Downloads/aaaaaa/MV_Display/gcc'
        ../../gcc/Makefile:10: recipe for target 'flash' failed
        make: *** [flash] Error 2
        Failed
    Failed


During build, it can't find the header file named stm32h7xx_hal.h anywhere where it's told to look for it. Possible reasons: somewhere in the build configuration, there is a missing/incorrect path to HAL header directory.
Fixing that in build settings (could be named differently; you are looking for preprocessor/compiler/linker settings) would probably be the best option as it will hook up any other HAL file in that folder. The parameter of interest is often named as "include folder path" or "library include path" or similar, that's where you set paths to folders, from which you can #include <my_file.h>.
Alternatively, you can manually place the missing file into some folder, where it will be found, such as next to main.cpp or where you have other headers. This approach will only work on per file basis.
